# How to silence output from "dbus-daemon" or "gio mount"

Tags: dbus

I want to mount a smb share in userspace using gio mount and a kerberos ticket. That works so far. But the dbus-daemon constantly writes out a message on stdout like

```
dbus-daemon[2305]: [session uid=26372637263 pid=2305] Activating service name=bla bla
```

or

```
Successfully activated service bla bla
```

To be able to use "gio mount" I have to restart the bash using

```
exec dbus-run-session -- bash
```

and I do that too to start a dbus-session. Only the mentioned messages bother me. STDOUT/STDERR redirection with

```
&> /dev/null
```

is not an option and consequently ignored or I use it incorrectly.

What can I do here?

Comment: Duplicate posting is discouraged - https://serverfault.com/questions/1113583/how-to-silence-output-from-dbus-daemon-or-gio-mount

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Bug 739076 : dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=739076)
has in the last entry the following workaround which might be useful.

The workaround is to add to the file
`/etc/rsyslog.d/drop-user-messages.conf`
the following lines :

```
:msg,contains,"Activating service name" stop
:msg,contains,"Successfully activated service"  stop
```

(I don't have your environment, so can't test if this applies there.)